# JPA - JPQL constructor expression throwing InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException on Enum data type

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpql

I am trying to determine how to resolve the following exception that is getting thrown for an enum custom data type by spring data jpa.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not determine appropriate instantiation strategy - no matching constructor found and one or more arguments did not define alias for bean-injection
```

The following jpql query simply creates a new result object for each record in the `Dates` table where the only value selected is a custom user defined data type.

```
@Query("select new DateDto(dayOfWeek) from Dates")
Set<DateDto> findAllDaysOfWeek();
```

```
public record DateDto(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek) {}
```

```
public enum DayOfWeek {
  MONDAY,
  TUESDAY,
  WEDNESDAY,
  THURSDAY,
  FRIDAY,
  SATURDAY,
  SUNDAY;
}
```

Comment: Assuming your Dates entity has the dayOfWeek property, the JPQL should be of the form "select new DateDto(d.dayOfWeek) from Dates d".  What does the Dates entity look like, and what object type is returned from a query just selecting "select d.dayOfWeek from dates d"?

Comment: @Chris Adding an alias d has no affect on the query. Running "select d.dayOfWeek from dates d" only works when the output is a collection of a single value; not multiple values within the same object. So, I could do a Set<DayOfWeek> however, I actually need more than just 1 column of data

Comment: I don't quite understand your statement. What does the Dates entity look like and what does "select d.dayOfWeek from dates d" return? I'm not asking as a workaround, I'm asking to understand what the DB and hibernate are giving back for the mapping - You mention "a custom user defined data type" but not any details on what it is or how it is mapped, and so we can't tell what type such a query might be returning for it and why it won't match your constructor. JPA can handle enums, so why do you need a custom data type for it?